# How to make sed avoid replacement after specific symbol

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am writing a script for formatting a Fortran source code.
Simple formatting, like having all keywords in capitals or in small letters, etc.
Here is the main command

```
sed -i -e "/^\!/! s/$small\s/$cap /gI" $filein
```

It replaces every keyword $small (followed by a space) by a keyword $caps. And the replacement happens only if the line does not start with the "!".
It does what it should. Question:

How to avoid replacement if "!" is encountered in the middle of a line.
Or more generally, how to replace patterns everywhere, but not after a specific symbol, which can be either in the beginning of the line or somewhere else.

Example:

```
Program test  ! It should not change the next program to caps
! Hi, is anything changing here? like program ?
This line does not have any key words
This line has Program and not exclamation mark.
```

"program" is a keyword. After running the script the result is:

```
PROGRAM test  ! It should not change the next PROGRAM to caps
! Hi, is anything changed here? like program ?
This line does not have any key words
This line has PROGRAM and not exclamation mark.
```

I want:

```
PROGRAM test  ! It should not change the next program to caps
! Hi, is anything changed here? like program ?
This line does not have any key words
This line has PROGRAM and not exclamation mark.
```

So far, I've failed to find a nice solution, which does the trick, hopefully with the sed command.

Comment: sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/); I'm assuming the bigger picture will see many, many of these types of changes in which case I'm wondering if it might make sense to spend some time on the top-level design, eg, a syntax (re)parser, or a script (`awk`? `perl`?) to process a library of such changes ... as opposed to what currently looks like 100's of separate `sed` calls ... ?

Comment: What about GNU awk? Try `awk -i inplace -v small="$small" -v cap="$cap" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS=OFS="!"} {gsub(small, cap, $1)}1' $filein`, see https://ideone.com/ugd5JE

Comment: So, does https://ideone.com/lM4fZC work for you?

Comment: N.B. `Program` and `program` are not the same so does the $small variable represent a regexp?

Answer (score 1):

The typicall way in sed is to:

- split the string into two parts - save one part in hold space.
- do operations on pattern space
- get hold space and shuffle for output.

Would be something along:

```
sed '/!/!b;/[^!]/{b};h;s/.*!//;x;s/!.*//;s/program/PROGRAM/gI;G;s/\n/!/'
```

- `/!/!b;` - if the line has no `!`, then print it and start over.
- `h;s/.*!//;x;s/!.*//` - put part after `!` in hold space, part before `!` in pattern space
- `s/program/PROGRAM/gI;` - do the substitution on part of the string
- `G;s/\n/!/` - grab the part from hold space and shuffle output - it's easy here.

Comment: It seems to me OP needs to only replace before the *first* `!`, and then `sed "h;s/^[^\!]*\!//;x;s/\!.*//;s/$small/$cap/gI;G;s/\n/\!/"` should work. The explanation is really helpful, BTW.

Comment: Yes, I saw something similar with splitting a string into two somewhere else, so perhaps it is the only way to solve my problem. Unfortunately, this particular command does not work for me. It just freezes and the output file is not written. It does not show any error messages either. I would guess that some minor thing is missing like a space or something.

Comment: @MikhailModestov See https://ideone.com/HT1QiM, it seems working.

Comment: OK, I've tried both ways. Indeed it works with those two particular lines. But if a line does not has the "!" it adds "!" and copies the text in the line. It looks I forgot to mention it in the question. So if a line does not have any keywords it must remain unchanged. Sorry for confusion and not describing it in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OP needs to convert multiple keywords to uppercase
- keywords to be capitalized do not include white space (eg, `program name` will need to be processed as two separate strings `program` and `name`)
- input delimiter is white space
- keywords with 'attached' non-alphanums will be ignored (eg, `Program,` will be ignored since `,` will be picked up as part of string) unless OP specifically includes the non-alphanum as part of the keyword definition (eg, keywords includes `Program,`)
- all keywords to be converted to uppercase (ie, not going to worry about any flags to switch between lowercase, uppercase, camelcase, etc)

Sample input data:

```
$ cat source.txt
Program test  ! It should not change the next program to caps        # change first 'Program'
! Hi, is anything changing here? like program or MarK?               # change nothing
This line does not have any key words ! except here - pRoGraM Mark   # change nothing
This line has Program and not exclamation mARk plus MarKer.          # change 'Program' and 'mARk' but not MarKer
Hi, hi, hI                                                           # change 'Hi,' and 'hi,' but not 'hI'
```

List of keywords provided in a separate file (whitespace delimited);

```
$ cat keywords.dat
program
mark hi,                  # 2 separate keywords: 'mark' and 'hi,' (comma included)
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v comment="!" '                                # define character after which conversions are to be ignored
FNR==NR { for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++)                    # first file contains keywords; process each field as a separate keywork
              keywords[toupper($i)]                 # convert to uppercase and use as index in associative array keywords[]
          next
        }
        { for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ )                   # second file, process each field separately
              { if ( $i == comment )                # if field is our comment character then stop processing rest of line else ...
                   break
                if ( toupper($i) in keywords )      # if current field is a keyword then convert to uppercase
                   $i=toupper($i)
              }
          print                                     # print the current line
        }
' keywords.dat source.txt
```

This generates:

```
PROGRAM test ! It should not change the next program to caps
! Hi, is anything changing here? like program or MarK?
This line does not have any key words ! except here - pRoGraM Mark
This line has PROGRAM and not exclamation MARK plus MarKer.
HI, HI, hI
```

**NOTES**:

- while `GNU awk` can be told to overwrite the input file (eg, `awk -i inplace` == `sed -i`), this will require a different approach for processing the `keywords.dat` file (to keep from overwriting with nothing)
- (quite a bit) of additional logic could be added to support uppercase vs lowercase vs camelcase vs whatever ... ignore or include non-alphanums in comparisons ... using multiple/different 'comment' characters ... standardizing other portions of (Fortran) code (eg, indentation) ... etc

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
small='Program ' caps='PROGRAM '
sed -E ':a;s/^([^!]*)('"$small"')/\1\n/;ta;s/\n/'"$caps"'/g' file
```

Replace any occurrence of the variable `$small` before the symbol `!` with a newline, then replace all newlines by the variable `$caps`.

N.B. The newline is chosen because it can not normally exist in any line presented by sed as it is the delimiter sed uses to present lines in the pattern space. Secondly, the words matching `$small` are iteratively replaced by a newline, then all newlines globally replaced by `$caps`. This allows for the replacement to by a superset of the first. If this were not the order of operations, the iterative process may become an endless loop.

If `$small` is to represent a case insensitive match, add the `i` flag to the first substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried suggested options, but all of them did not work as expected for the whole file.
I have ended up with multiple sed commands; I am sure that it is not the best solution, but it works for me and does what I need.
My main problem was to avoid replacement after "!" if it appears somewhere in the middle of the line.
So I switched this problem to the one I could handle.

```
 sed -i -e "/^\!/! s/!/!c7u!!c7u!/" $filein               # 1. If a line does NOT start with !, search next "!" and replace it with "!c7u!!c7u!"
  sed -i "s/!c7u!/\n/" $filein                             # 2. Move that comment to a new line
    for ((i=0; i<$nwords; i++ )); do                       # Loop through all keywords
      word=${words[$i]}                                    # Take a keyword from the list
      small=${word,,}                                      # Write it in small letters
      cap=${word^^}                                        # Write it in capitals
      sed -i -e "/^\!/! s/$small\b/$cap/gI" $filein        # 3. Actual replacement in lines not starting with "!"
    done

    sed -i -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n!c7u//;ta' -e 'P;D' $filein   # 4. Undo step 1-2, moving inline comments back
```